# latlng is undefined (trying to use geolocation in the browser) (gmaps4rails v2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

**map.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  getLocation = ->
    if navigator.geolocation
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition userPosition showError options
    else
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.")

  handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'
  handler.buildMap 
    provider: {}
    internal: {id: 'map'}
  , ->
    handler.panTo latlng
```

**geolocation.js.coffee**

```
userPosition = (position) ->
  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude)
  alert(latlng)

showError = (error) ->
  switch error.code
    when error.PERMISSION_DENIED
      alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.")
    when error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE
      alert("Location information is unavailable.")
    when error.TIMEOUT
      alert("The request to get user location timed out.")
    when error.UNKNOWN_ERROR
      alert("An unknown error occurred.")

options =
  enableHighAccuracy: false
  timeout: 5000
```

I feel like maybe I don't have a grasp on global variables? 
I tried moving the `getLocation` call all over the place...

I tried putting it all in the same file...

I tried moving handler above (outside) of the `jQuery` ready function... that gave a different error about _ not being defined.

I threw the `alert(latlng)` in there just to see if it was even hitting that function... it's not.

I'm trying out the new [gmaps4rails gem](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) and struggling a bit.  I checked out the info over at [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) too, which this code is pretty close to.

Comment: where is `getLocation` called?

Comment: I was under the (apparently false) impression that with coffee you could place functions inline like I did there, and it would run it.  I tried moving the function all around (above the `ready`, and below, inside and out) and calling it directly with `getLocation`, but had the same undefined latlng.

Comment: js vars cant be shared from one js file to another, not this way actually

Comment: So would I build the map entirely in each the success callback, and the failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont understand your code but here is the idea:

```
handler = Gmaps.build 'Google'
handler.buildMap { internal: {id: 'map'} }, ->

  positionSuccess = (position) ->
    handler.map.centerOn
      lat: position.coords.latitude
      lng: position.coords.longitude

  positionError = ->

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError)
```

Comment: (would require 2.0.3)

Comment: `handler.map.centerOn` did the trick.  Could you give a list of methods that we can call on the map?

Comment: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/objects/map.coffee